# How to change H3 color in bootstrap using CSS file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, colors, header

I have a webpage here: http://www.indiespil.dk/aitasi-under-construction-page/Aitasi/image/

I downloaded a HTML template, and I think it is using Bootstrap. I am no programmer, so this is the first time I am using HTML, CSS, Bootstrap and all that kind of stuff.

Everything is perfectly okay on my webpage as for now, except 1 thing: the text color in the second section, where it says "Competition", "Game wallet", "Indie Coins" and "Community"

These words are black, and I need them to be white instead.

The text is called

as for now, which has the color code #000000 and a size of 18px.

I need the h3 to be used lower on the website, but I would like to make a custom header (h7 for instance) that has the same size as h3, but is white instead.

I tried making a h7 and it actually came out white and the same size, but when I entered h7 in my index file it didn't align, as the rest.

How can I make it align properly?

Thanks.

Comment: http://imgur.com/t9Xah0o u have some finished tags which you didn't started. if you have firefox browser, open the source code with ctrl+u and check the source code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You dont need to create an H7 header element simply add the `!important` rule to a separate class in your css when changing the colour like this.

**HTML**

```
<h3 class="whiteTextOverride"> example with white text override </h3> 
<h3> example with default colour </h3>
```

**CSS**

```
.whiteTextOverride
{
 color: white !important;
}
```

This will override the colour set by bootstrap and allow you to choose a specific colour for the text in that header only.

P.S. its worth mentioning that you shouldnt go crazy with the !important feature in css as it can affect other classes if you are not careful with it so use it minimally and have a look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) article on when you should use it. Good luck!

---

### Example

```css
h3
{
 color: red;   
}

.whiteTextOverride
{
 color: white !important;
}

.darkBackground
{
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="darkBackground">
  <h3 class="whiteTextOverride"> example with white text override </h3> 
  <h3> example with default colour </h3> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like, I'm guessing the h7 tag was not aligned because the h3 element is preceded by the .service class.  If you want to make a h7 you have to make sure it has a class of .service before the h7 tag in the css.  The h3 tag is setup like so:

```
.service h3{
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

You'd want to do something like this:

```
.service h7{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Hope that helps.